# 'workbooks.worksheets.activate' works, but '.select' does not

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone tell me why, when I refer to a particular sheet, I could use:

```
workbooks("A").worksheets("B").activate
```

but not

```
workbooks("A").worksheets("B").select
```

?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't select a sheet in a non-active workbook.

You must first activate the workbook, then you can select the sheet.

```
workbooks("A").activate
workbooks("A").worksheets("B").select
```

When you use Activate it automatically activates the workbook.

Note you can select >1 sheet in a workbook:

`activeworkbook.sheets(array("sheet1","sheet3")).select`

but only one sheet can be Active, and if you activate a sheet which is not part of a multi-sheet selection then those other sheets will become un-selected.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I remember I read from somewhere that .select is not recommended to use, do you happen to know why?

Comment: That advice typically comes from using macro-recorder-generated without any edits. Typically the recorder generates code like `Range("A1").Select` then `Selection.Copy` whereas it's much cleaner just to do `Range("A1").Copy`. If your code uses `Select` (particularly on ranges) then it can break if the "wrong" sheet is active, making your macro much less robust. Avoiding select and working directly on the object itself is faster and less brittle.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot! Can I ask one more question? Under what circumstances, the activesheet will be changed, say if the current activesheet is B and then I change the format or value of a cell in sheetA, will the activesheet become sheetA?

Comment: The activesheet only changes if you set it in code or change it manually. However, it's easy when you have a lot of code to forget which sub does or doesn't switch sheets, so it's best to avoid relying on some specific sheet being active at any given time and instead always refer to it directly (by name or by codeName).

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate it!

Comment: So to select a sheet in an inactive workbook one needs to `.Activate` it and then activate previously active workbook?

Comment: Yes but typically there's no need to do that

Comment: @TimWilliams what do you mean? I run a macro in one workbook. *In case* I want to put some data in another workbook, I want my macro to prepare that workbook: select a certain sheet, hilight certain cells.