# VBA Excel : Compile Error when using .activate on a sheet

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I encounter the following error within my Excel macro when I tried to execute it :
Compilation Error : Function or Variable expected.

### Here is my code :

```
            'On split le libellé afin de récupérer la chaîne de caractère source1 à rechercher dans la colonne B du PSR
            TabSrcDoubleEntree = Split(PtoutPar(j).Nom, "/")
            ' on récupère la ligne du PSR (colonne B) dans laquelle la chaîne source 1 (=TabSrcDoubleEntree(0)) est renseignée
            Set sheet = Workbooks(PFile).Sheets(ParMap(j).Parametrage.SrcFeuille)
            **With sheet.Activate**
                Set celluleRowRange = .Range("B", .Range("B").End(xlUp))
                Set celluleFind = celluleRowRange.Find(TabSrcDoubleEntree(0), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                celluleRowFind = celluleFind.Row
            End With
            'on initialise la ligne à partir de laquelle on fait la recherche à "c.Row"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PFeuilleDest).Cells(iDest, ParMap(j).Parametrage.DestCol).Value = Workbooks(PFile).Sheets(ParMap(j).Parametrage.SrcFeuille).Cells(celluleFind.Row + ParMap(j).Parametrage.SrcPremiereLigne, ParMap(j).Parametrage.SrcCol).Value
```

=> Does anyone know why the instruction sheet.Activate is not correct ??

THanks a lot
Simon

Comment: You don't need `.Activate` 
[INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Have you [activated the workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410705/43846)?

Comment: replace `With sheet.Activate` with two lines: `sheet.Activate` and `With ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

The `With "this"` statement is used to perform the following block from the context of `"this"`. In your case you are performing the block from the context of the `Activate` function, rather than the `sheet` itself, which is throwing a compile error. I would recommend changing it to the following

```
' Perform the following from the context of sheet    
With sheet
    .Activate
    Set celluleRowRange = .Range("B", .Range("B").End(xlUp))
    ' ...
End With
```